# Select Excel cells by condition and paste them into Word as an image

Tags: vba, excel

For my software regression test I use Excel to compare numerical values between reference and release candidate version:

**Header of Excel sheet for regression testing:**
[image: img]

**Body of Excel sheet for regression testing:**

[image: img2]
This data is copied by the following vba macro as an image to Word:

```
Sub Copy2Word()

Dim ZeilenAnzahl As Integer
Dim MaxBlock As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Copyrange, Zelle As String
ZeilenAnzahl = 80
MaxBlock = 10

Dim objWord, objDoc As Object
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

For i = 1 To MaxBlock
    Startrow = 1 + (i - 1) * ZeilenAnzahl
    Lastrow = ZeilenAnzahl + (i - 1) * ZeilenAnzahl
    Let Zelle = "A" & Startrow
    If IsEmpty(Range(Zelle).value) = False Then
       Let Copyrange = "A" & Startrow & ":" & "I" & Lastrow
       Range(Copyrange).Select
       Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
       objWord.Visible = True
       objWord.Selection.Paste
       objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

The macro groupes 80 lines of the Excel sheet to one image. I want to change this in a manner that only lines are selected which have a real deviation (Column "G") bigger than the permissible deviation (Column "D"). The macro shall collect 80 lines which fulfill this condition and copy them to Word or copy the rest if now more lines are found.

How would you realize this?

Comment: FWIW you won't be able to select non-contiguous cells and copy them as an image, without including what's between. So if you want to copy as an image you first need to write all the cells that match the criteria to someplace in the workbook, as a single range, then copy that.

Comment: Don't quote me but can you hide the rows you don't want to see and then copy?

Comment: If a understand it correctly I've to perform some preprocessing before I can select the rows for the image export to Word. Hiding the rows which fulfill my condition are certainly one way, copiing all rows which didn't fulfill the condition another. Nevertheless I look for a solution which does the job within my macro.

Comment: Using Union to gather all the rows matching condition, then unionRange.EntireRow.Hidden = True then copying entire range should work  (Ibelieve) and be efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried an other solution.
I cleaned your data sheet and I created a new sheet with the only selectable rows and I run this vba code (edit sht_data var) :

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'sheets
Dim sht_temp As String
Dim sht_data As String
sht_data = "Feuil1" 'TO EDIT
sht_temp = "temp"

'temp sheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each sh In Worksheets
If sh.Name = "temp" Then sh.Delete
Next
Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = sht_temp

'copy header in temp sheet
Worksheets(sht_data).Rows("1:1").Copy
Worksheets(sht_temp).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

'last row
Dim LastRowData As Integer
Dim LastRowtemp As Integer
LastRowData = Worksheets(sht_data).Cells(Worksheets(sht_data).Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

'Copy selectable result in a new sheet
For j = 1 To LastRowData

LastRowtemp = Worksheets(sht_temp).Cells(Worksheets(sht_temp).Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1


If Worksheets(sht_data).Range("H" & j).Value = "yes" Then
    Worksheets(sht_data).Rows(j & ":" & j).Copy

    Worksheets(sht_temp).Select
    Worksheets(sht_temp).Range("A" & LastRowtemp).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End If

Next j


Dim ZeilenAnzahl As Integer
Dim MaxBlock As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Copyrange, Zelle As String
ZeilenAnzahl = 80
MaxBlock = 10

Worksheets(sht_temp).Activate

Dim objWord, objDoc As Object
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

For i = 1 To MaxBlock
    Startrow = 1 + (i - 1) * ZeilenAnzahl
    LastRow = ZeilenAnzahl + (i - 1) * ZeilenAnzahl
    Let Zelle = "A" & Startrow
    If IsEmpty(Range(Zelle).Value) = False Then
       Let Copyrange = "A" & Startrow & ":" & "I" & LastRow
       Range(Copyrange).Select
       Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
       objWord.Visible = True
       objWord.Selection.Paste
       objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
    End If
Next i


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

This way is working for me.

Let me know what about you.

Comment: This way is also working for me. I made only two small changes: `Worksheets(sht_data).Rows("1:19").Copy` and `If Worksheets(sht_data).Range("H" & j).value = "no" Then`. Of course I changed the value of `sht_data`, too.

Comment: Great happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

**step1** : you can add a new column to have a selectable condition with this formula, which you shall add to column "H":

```
=IF(AND(G7<=D7;G7>=-D7);"yes";"no")
```

**step2** : Add in first of your vba code the filter with this code:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:H").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="no"
```

**step3** : to be sure to copy only visible row, replace your copy methode by xlCellTypeVisible like this :

```
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
```

Let me know if it's working ;)

Comment: Excel gives me the run time error 1004 complaining about the non connected range of selected cells of the command `Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture`. If I skip **step3** then it's partly working. Only partly because the `AutoFilter` hides the header of my Excel sheet which I want to copy as image too.

Comment: A small hint regarding **step2** : To fulfill the condition described in my question, the auto filter criterion shall be `Criteria1:="no"`.